# Sizing radiator

Tags: heat-transfer

I'd like to do a DIY project to reuse my home AC heat output to heat my pool that is located very nearby the AC radiator. I planned on fitting a second radiator directly onto the heat output and hook the pool pump onto it.

Let's say I know or have an idea of the amount of heat that the AC can output, how do I size the second radiator?

For optimal heat transfer, would the 2 radiator needs to be identical?
What happen if it is oversized, will it reduces the performances or just be too expensive for nothing? What parameter should I look for, only thermal resistance?

Thanks!

Comment: Air to air coupling coefficient will be poor compared to a water coupled heat exchanger.

Comment: Have the AC people design the proper radiator / condenser directly into the pool water - much more efficient.

Comment: It's a DIY project, the goal is not to hire somebody to do it. Having something custom made will be very expensive. Also, it will be air coupled as the AC radiator isn't designed for water coupling and I don't plan on changing the actual installation